# What is proper way to show Facebook avatar using AngularFire

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, angularfire2

In my app I'd like to show avatar of logged Facebook user. I haven't found any elegant solution.

To show an avatar of user you need to provide two things: `user_id` and `accessToken`. `user_id` is available any where via `AngularFireAuth` service, but I haven't found `accessToken` anywhere but in logging method.

I'm using `"@angular/fire": "6.0.3"`, and login with redirect method.

My solution. When I log in user, the `accessToken` is stored in local storage. It is because `getRedirectResult()` method returns credentials only while user is logging. When user is already logged in, method doesn't return credentials.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.progress.show();
  this.angularFireAuth.getRedirectResult()
    .then((uc: any) => {
      const token = uc?.credential?.accessToken;
      if (token) {
        localStorage.setItem('fbuser', token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }
      this.progress.hide();
    });
}

loginFacebook(): void {
  const provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();  
  this.angularFireAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

and when I need to display the image:

```js
constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

this.user$ = this.auth.user;
this.avatarSrc$ = this.user$.pipe(
  map(u => u.providerData[0].uid),
  map(uid => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('fbuser');
    return `http://graph.facebook.com/${uid}/picture?type=square&access_token=${accessToken}}`
  }),
);
```

I'm not sure it is best solution, especially use of local storage.

Have some one had similar problem and found better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use firestore in our app to store the avatar.
On sign in with a provider, we set a user document in firestore (when it's a new user) and we copy the provider avatar url into the user data:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.progress.show();
  this.angularFireAuth.getRedirectResult()
    .then((uc: any) => {
      // skip data creation if user is not new
      if (!uc.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) { return Promise.resolve(); }
      const user = uc.user;
      return this.angularFirestore.collection('user_collection').doc(user.uid).set({
          avatarURL: user.photoURL || '',
          email: user.email || '',
          displayName: user.displayName || ''
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.progress.hide();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    });
}

loginFacebook(): void {
  const provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();  
  this.angularFireAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
}
```

Then in the app, with the authState, we fetch the user data in DB containing the avatar url:

```js
constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

this.authState$ = this.auth.authState;
this.user$ = this.authState$.pipe(
  switchMap(state => {
    return (!!state) ? 
      this.angularFirestore.collection('user_collection').doc(state.uid).valueChanges() : 
      of(null);
  })
);
this.avatarSrc$ = this.user$.pipe(
  map(user => user.avatarURL)
);
```

Comment: Yes, it seems legite. Meanwhile I consulted this on the angularfire's github and the answer is the same. Thanks.